# asp.net configuration read subsection error

Tags: asp.net, config

In config file I had an email section with some values and custom configuration manager read it fine. Now I need to add a subsection to Email section and the following line gives an error:

var configInstance = (ProgConfiguration)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Prog");

The error message is: "The Configuration property 'EmailAccounts' may not be derived from ConfigurationSection."

```
<Prog Debug="true">
<Email 
FromEmail="me@me.com" 
EmailSubject="Your content" 
MailServerList="mymail_com">
<EmailAccounts
StandardEmail="one@me.com"
SupportEmail="two@me.com"/>
</Email>
</Prog>
```

Any help please?

Comment: It would probably help to see your code that your are using to create the custom section.

Answer (score 8):

Change EmailAccounts to a ConfigurationElement not a ConfigurationSection